# global set error_handler

Tags: php, linux, error-handling

I have this code, how can set error_handler to all the functions. right now error_handler get called only if an error occurs outside foo1 & foo2.

```
set_error_handler('error_handler',-1 & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_USER_NOTICE);

function error_handler($exception) {
// log the error
}


function foo1(){
throw new Exception("Error validating user input.");
        exit(0);
}


function foo2(){
throw new Exception("Error validating user input.");
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Those two `exit(0);` make no sense. That code is never executed. Additionally the parameter of your `error_handler` function is not really correct.

Answer (score 0):

`set_error_handler` is set the global error handler, it is already for all the functions.
For using `set_error_handler`, you should use `trigger_error` to trigger an error, not throwing an Exception, an uncaught Exception will cause a Fatal Error only.

You are use `Exception` in your function, then it should be  [set_exception_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Answer (score 0):

The `error_handler` only gets called for errors that are triggered by PHP itself or using [`trigger_error`](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

But your `foo1()` and `foo2()` functions are throwing exceptions; those would have to be handled by [`set_exception_handler()`](http://sg3.php.net/set_exception_handler).